# During training why data no longer exists on the device error occurs.?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Error using trainNetwork (line 140) The data no longer exists on the device.

Error in ownet2 (line 50) net = trainNetwork(imdstrain,layers,opts);

Caused by: Error using nnet.internal.cnngpu.reluForward The data no longer exists on the device.

my code is

```
clc; clear;
imdstrain = imageDatastore('D:\train\elbow','IncludeSubfolders',true,'LabelSource', 'foldernames');
imdstrain.ReadFcn = @(filename)readAndPreproc(filename);
layers = [
    imageInputLayer([256 256 3])
      convolution2dLayer(5,96)
      reluLayer
      convolution2dLayer(5,192)
      reluLayer
      maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)
      convolution2dLayer(3,256)
      reluLayer
      convolution2dLayer(3,256)
      reluLayer
      maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)
      convolution2dLayer(3,384)
      reluLayer
      convolution2dLayer(3,384)
      reluLayer  
      maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)
      convolution2dLayer(3,256)
      reluLayer
      convolution2dLayer(3,256)
      reluLayer
      fullyConnectedLayer(5)
      softmaxLayer
      classificationLayer];
opts = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'InitialLearnRate', 0.001, ... 
    'LearnRateSchedule', 'piecewise', ...
    'L2Regularization', 0.0001, ... 
    'MaxEpochs', 25, ...
    'MiniBatchSize', 50, ...
    'Verbose', true, ...
    'Plots','training-progress');
net = trainNetwork(imdstrain,layers,opts);
```

Comment: What do you see when you call  `gpuDevice()` before you train your network? Are you short on memory on the GPU?

Comment: this is what i get. Name: 'Quadro P400'
                     Index: 1
                 SIMDWidth: 32
               TotalMemory: 2.1475e+09
           AvailableMemory: 1.6003e+09

Comment: Hmm. Your GPU seems perfectly fine for GPU-accellerated programming in MatLab, and you still have a significant portion of the device's RAM available.

The error indicates that data it needs on the GPU's memory is no longer there. Normally you would get this error if a variable has been cleared from the gpu (e.g. using `reset(gpuDevice);`), and you try to access it later. 

I did some digging around and thought this could be worth a shot: Could you try adding `'ExecutionEnvironment','gpu'` in your call to `trainingOptions`?

Comment: i added this line 'ExecutionEnvironment','gpu', ... in training options as said. between initial learn rate and learn rate schedule. Same error occurs. The data no longer exists on the device.

Comment: I really wouldn't know then, I do not have any experience combining neural networks and parallel programming. I suppose you could alter the `ExecutionEnvironment` to `cpu` if your problem is not too computationally expensive, that should fix the problem (but make the code a lot slower). Maybe someone else here can help you, so wait around for someone elses response. You could try raising your issue on the Mathworks forums as well.

Comment: however, as you said (e.g. using reset(gpuDevice);) this i had done once, since during training once it went out of memory. so when i googled for solutions i found this (e.g. using reset(gpuDevice);), and executed  it. now facing this problem. Even i asked this same in mathworks. did not get answer still like you also. Thanks alot for your kind suggestions, help.

Comment: `reset(gpuDevice)` clears all data that is currently on the memory of the GPU (called 'device'). After that, you should be able to allocate memory on the GPU again, and so should `trainNetwork`. Some errors can cause the gpu-matlab link to become bugged, but I have only seen those when working with self-written GPU code, I do not think that happened in your case (but you could try restarting MatLab, I guess). From your code, it looks like you're working with a 256x256 image, which should not be near enough to hit your memory limits either. Or do you have a lot of other variables on the GPU?

Comment: ok. Thank you. Whether the image size is the problem here.? i tried reducing the image size to 227x227. Still i get the same error. reset(gpudevice) made me to cause this error.